# Can I use form elements in innerHTML in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

HEADER TAGS ARE WORKING IN innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById ("x").innerHTML="<h1>something<h1>";
```

---

BUT FORM ELEMENTS ARE NOT WORKING!!

```
document.getElementById ("x").innerHTML="<input type="text">";
```

---

I want use form elements on some condition, If a radio button is clicked.

Comment: `document.getElementById ("x").innerHTML="<input type='text'>";`

Comment: It's not working because you messed up the quotes. Learn how to use the console (F12).

Comment: I recommend working through some basic JavaScript tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code closely:

```
document.getElementById ("x").innerHTML="<input type="text">";
// -------------------------------------^------------^----^-^
```

This is part of why JavaScript has always had two different kinds of quotes (now three, as of ES2015). So we can use `'` for the string, and have `"` inside the string:

```
document.getElementById ("x").innerHTML='<input type="text">';
```

Although we could just escape the `"` if we wanted:

```
document.getElementById ("x").innerHTML="<input type=\"text\">";
// --------------------------------------------------^-----^
```